# Is it common for Android View objects to manage background threads?

Tags: android, user-interface, concurrency, signal-processing

I come from more of a C++ background where we have the luxury of destructors for gracefully stopping background operations (including when necessary in UI components).  I'm working on a little android side project in which I want to visually render wav files.  I'm not interested in using any libraries to do so, it's more of an exercise than anything else.

I'm trying to create a View object that effectively can be given a WavFile object (one that I have designed myself which uses a small RIFF parsing framework that I wrote).  The goal of this View component would be to allow for rendering the waveform at different zoom levels.

The main view object (WavView) extends HorizontalScrollView and has a single waveform renderer child.  The idea is that the child can grow horizontally larger as the zoom factor increases, allowing the user to scroll through the zoomed wave form.

As the zoom factor increases, the view will decrease the reduction range of the samples it reads in, e.g. if the reduction range is 500, each sample in the reduced data set is reduced[0] = average(source[0, 499]), reduced[1] = average(source[500, 999]), etc.  The reduction range is dynamically computed based on the width of the WavView object, so by default the zoom factor is 1, meaning the waveform fits exactly inside the WavView (e.g. no scrolling).

This means every time that the zoom factor or the parent width changes, I must read through the wave file and perform all reduction based on the reduction range.  The framework that I've designed for parsing the data should also be useful in playback of that data.  Since wav PCM samples are little endian, this framework converts them to big endian so that it can be used with playback as well.

All of this isn't cheap and clearly has to be done on a separate thread.  I would like to be able encapsulate all of this functionality within the same type, making it super simple to pass a wave file to it and be rendered.  While the samples are being reduced, the parent will show a progress indicator and when complete will show the rendered waveform.

But when I hit the case of perhaps another file being set or the activity being killed or simply the view being removed from the layout tree, I obviously need to stop the thread.  Is this something that android views commonly implement?  Should I do this another way?  I'd like to maintain as much encapsulation as possible.

EDIT:  The AsyncTask appears to be something that might be useful for accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this something that android views commonly implement?

No, it is not common practice for views to deal with threading at all. Views in Android are views in the MVP sense. They should be able to render themselves very quickly with the data passed to them and not really "aware" of any complex business logic. It probably doesn't make sense to pass a waveform to a view because, without threading, interpreting the waveform would bog down the system, as you stated.

You'd probably be better served by writing a presenter that could take a waveform and render it to a bitmap in a background thread. You could bind this to your custom view in a way such that the presenter posts a finished bitmap to the view, which it can render very quickly, but the presenter is always working on writing the next waveform to a different bitmap in another thread. This presenter should be bound to an Activity or Fragment lifecycle and you'd have to handle things like the view being removed, zoomed or resized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This is actually where I was planning to go, handling the parsing of the file and drawing to a bitmap, since it also wouldn't be cheap to draw a path several hundred points long during onDraw.  I didn't realize that I didn't mention that part (there's so much text already).  I was getting at whether each view instance should manage a separate loading drawing thread, but perhaps it's better for a single job queue to handle each parse and draw operation, instead of many at once.